# p:dataGrid does not align multiple columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, alignment, multiple-columns

I would like to display a list of label/input using `<p:dataGrid>`. My code is so simple, but I can't get the expected result.

This is my code:

```
<p:dataGrid columns="2" value="#{scriptManagerForm.params}" var="conf">
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="#{conf.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText value="#{conf.value}" required="true" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
```

And this is the result that I get now:

[image: results obtained]

And this is what I need to get:

[image: expected]

Comment: Where did you read `p:datagrid` supports the column tag? So you code is indeed simple but so wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You need the property layout="grid" in the dataGrid

Comment: No, after add it, the problem persists

Comment: when you do the layout grid, the first component that takes it will take it as a column, and when the number of columns is filled, it will do the line break, If you're using <p:row> tags or column tags, that might be the problem, try removing the column tags and just leave the outputlabel and the input text tagas

Comment: @IvanChavarria: No, the p:column is useless in this regard ,the dataGrid has no knowledge of them (they have no renderer)... Putting plain divs in there instead of the `p:columns` and giving them a fixed width helps

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you need a `panelGrid` instead of a `dataGrid`.

Inside you can also work with `<p:row>` and `<p:column>` if you want.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml

I hope this helps!

Comment: no i have tried **panelgrid** inside **datalist** and that does not work

Comment: I use @DataGrid because the number of @<p:inputText> is dynamic

Comment: @Kukeltje because panel grid will consider that there one component inside who is ui;repeat and will display it in the first column